# Add input data on the fly to Hadoop Map-Reduce Job?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Can I append input files or input data to a map-reduce job while it's running without creating a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

I think in theory you can add more files into the input as long as it:

1. Matches your FileInputFormat pattern
2. Happens before InputFormat.getSplits() call which really gives you a very short time after you submit a job.

Regarding the race condition after splits are computed, note that append to existing files is only available since the version [0.21.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-265).

And even if you can modify your files, your split points already precomputed and most likely your new data will not be picked up by mappers. Though, I doubt that it will lead to a crash of your flow.

What you can experiment with is to disable splits within a file (that is assign a mapper per file) and try to append. I think some data that had a chance to get flushed may end up in a mapper (that's just my wild guess).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm going to assume that the upshot of this answer is "no".

Comment: Well try my suggestion at the end with disabled splits. May it will help

Comment: Well I think that plays into the race condition issue. I would need a guarantee that some mapper will always get the new data, and it doesn't seem like that's really a possibility.

Comment: if you close files BEFORE the mappers end streaming, they might pick up all the data (but again this needs some experimenting)

Answer (score 1):

Effectively the answer is "no".  The splits are computed very early in the game: and after that your new files will not be included.